# Emberjs Set CurrentUserController from LoginController

Tags: ember.js

I have a currentUser objectController :

```
App.CurrentUserController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  username: 'Test',
  email : 'test@test.com'
})
```

When a user logs in, I want to set the currentUser's username, email etc:

```
App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
needs: 'currentUser',
login: function(){
    var self = this;
    var data = this.getProperties('username', 'password');
    self.set('errorMessage', null);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      mimeType: "text/xml",
      success: function(response){
        App.CurrentUser.set('username', data.username);
        App.CurrentUser.set('email', data.email);
        self.transitionToRoute('home');
      },
      error: function(){
         self.set('errorMessage', true);
      }
    });
       }
   });
```

I've tried above with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no App.CurrentUser instance available.

```
App.CurrentUser.set('username', data.username);
```

Since you are using 'needs', you can access that controller like this:

```
this.get('controllers.currentUser')
```

Make sure your *'this'* is correctly binded in your XHR response.

Finally, Since Ember getters/setters supports 'paths', you can set properties like this:

```
this.set('controllers.currentUser.email', data.email);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great.

Is it also possible to do the same thing at the Route level. If I go to '/test/:id' - I want to be able to also store that :id parameter in the currentUser object.?

Comment: Broadly speaking, Yes, it is possible though when working with Ember apps, the more important question is "If you should do certain logic at a certain spot or not".

So, Yes, it should be possible but maybe not advocated. If you explain your scenario better, maybe I can help then.